# Creating multiple loggers in Python to different outputs in the same module

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

So I want to create multiple loggers in the same module

```
log = logging.getLogger('FirstLogger')
plog = logging.getLogger('SecondLogger')
```

and I want to configure each logger separately.

so I added a FileHandler for plog that only takes logging.INFO or above while the FileHandler for log would take logging.DEBUG or above.

I have created an init_logger() function that takes in the instance of the logger to perform the configuration on

```
def init_logger(logger, fmode, cmode)
```

So i want FirstLogger to log to a file that i created separately for it and log with DEBUG level. I would do

```
log = logging.getLogger('FirstLogger')
init_logger(log,logging.DEBUG,logging.INFO)

plog = logging.getLogger('SecondLogger')
init_logger(plog,logging.INFO,logging.INFO)
```

In init_logger I specify different files for the FileHandler and set the levels according to what is passed to init_logger.

```
flog = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
flog.setLevel(fmode)
flog.setFormatter(...)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(cmode)
console.setFormatter(...)

log.addhandler(flog)
log.addHandler(console)
```

The problem I have is that even though 'log' has console set level to INFO and the FileHandler to DEBUG I still only get INFO in both the file and the console. I can't figure out what is wrong with what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the level of the file handler to DEBUG, but you do not set the level of the logger itself to DEBUG

```
log.setLevel(min(cmode, fmode))
```

Comment: Thanks @Pedru. I indeed forgot to set the level of the logger itself.

Comment: glad I could help =)